# c# how to make a tabpage visibe to only some users based on roles

Tags: c#

```
private void tabPage3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)this.tabPage3).Enabled = false;
}

private void tabPage4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (GloballsClass.Role == "student")
   {
       ((Control)this.tabPage4).Visible = false;
       this.tabPage4.Hide();
    }
}

private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GloballsClass.Role == "student")
    {
        tabPage1.Hide();
    }
}

private void WelcomePage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF?

Comment: the main thing you are doing wrong here is waiting until they click the tab to hide it, you should do checks like that in the load event of the form

Answer (score 1):

I've done this some time ago. The problem is that there is no property `Visible` and `Enabled` is doing not the things you would like to do.

So here is how i'm doing it:

```
// Put this over the constructor
private TabPage tabPage4ToShowForNotStudents = this.tabPage4;
private TabPage tabPage1ToShowForNotStudents = this.tabPage1;
```

Then you have to subscribe the Load-Method of your Form:

```
void WelcomePage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GloballsClass.Role != "student")
    {
        yourTabControl.TabPages.Add(this.tabPage4ToShowForNotStudents);
        yourTabControl.TabPages.Add(this.tabPage1ToShowForNotStudents);
    }
}
```

Now it will add the `TabPage` to your `TabControl` if the Role is not `student`. If it is it will not be added.

Be sure to not have them added in the designer otherwise it will not work.

Hope this is useful :)

Answer (score -1):

thanks guys.i have sorted out the problem.
 private void WelcomePage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GloballsClass.Role == "student")
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage5);
            }
            else
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage4);

```
        }
    }
```